# particular solution $e^x/x^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

1. $y''-2y'+y=e^x/x^3$

please suggest particular solution

2. $y''-4y=-2x+e^-2x$

$yp = Ax+b+Cxe^-2x+De^-2x $

Isn't this it ?

Comment: You cannot use that method to solve this problem unless you got very lucky. You will have to use variation of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$y''-2y'+y=\dfrac {e^x}{x^3}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(ye^{-x})''=\dfrac 1 {x^3}$$
Integrate twice.

---

For the second equation:
$$y''-4y=-2x+e^{-2x}$$
The guess should be:
$$y_p=Ax+B+Cxe^{-2x}$$

Comment: thank you so much it was helpful !

Comment: you 're welcome @wooHwangbo

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of the complementary equation is
 $$y_c=a_1e^x+a_2xe^x$$ Let $$y_1=e^x, y_2=xe^x.$$ The 'variation of parameters' writes a particular solution $y_p$ in the form $$y_p=u_1+u_2y_2$$ where $u_1 \text { and }u_2$ are functions of $x$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix}y_1&y_2\\y_1'&y_2'\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1'\\u_2'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{e^x}{x^3}\end{bmatrix}$$ Thus $$\begin{bmatrix}e^x&xe^x\\e^x&(x+1)e^x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1'\\u_2'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{e^x}{x^3}\end{bmatrix}$$ This system is easily solved for $u_1' \text { and }u_2'$ by Cramer's Rule. Then $u_1 \text { and }u_2$ are found by easy integrations.

Comment: it was good to think in a different way , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try a form of solution $e^x \sum\limits_{i=-1}^2 c_i x^i$ to find:

$$y(x) = c_1 e^x+c_2 e^x x+\frac{e^x}{2 x}$$

Comment: This is my first time here, so I didn't know much about the form.

Comment: thanks for your hint !